# Are there any placeholder numbers in a programming context?

Tags: language-agnostic, placeholder

> The terms **foobar**, **foo**, **bar**, **baz** and
> **qux** are sometimes used as placeholder
> names (also referred to as
> metasyntactic variables) in computer
> programming or computer-related
> documentation.

[...As stated here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar)

Are there any placeholders for numbers?

**Update:**

To be more clear, here are some examples where it would be useful to have placeholder numbers:

- Credit card numbers
- Licence plates
- Phone numbers
- Bar codes (the actual numbers)
- *Freestyle* (any length and any numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) lists many magic numbers, in particular the famous DEADBEEF. However, it's often a bad practice to use magic numbers since they don't have a common meaning, so they aren't used as often as 'foo' or 'bar' (except, maybe, hex addressed like DEADBEEF). I tend to use all zeros or 1234567890 for things like credit card numbers / phone numbers in my tests. Occasionally I use 42 just for fun but only even then I make sure it's clear that it's a joke.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there are any standard ones, but..

You could do 1337..

Or 42 (the meaning of life)